# Input precedence value and stack precedence value

Tags: data-structures, prefix, infix-notation

There is some eror in input precedence value and stack precedence value for conversion of infix expression to prefix expression(in the table).
Please provide the corrected value:

```
|Symbol|     Stack |  Input   |
|      |Precedence |Precedence|
|------|-----------|----------|
  '+'      1            2                
  '-'      1            2                
  '*'      3            4                
  '%'      3            4                
  '/'      3            4                
  '^'      6            5                
  '$'      6            5                
  '('     -2            0                
  ')'      0            9                
  '#'     -1           -1               
 Default   8             7                


infix expression: (((a+b)*c-(d-e))^(f+g))
Expected prefix: ^-*+abc-de+fg
I got: -*+abc-de+fg^
```

Comment: Without know the rule set we cannot guarantee which value needs correcting. But maybe this is actuallly your homework, so you need to check the full question.

Comment: `^` is the only one that has a lower "input precedence" than "stack precedence". I understand that this is because `^` is right-associative whereas other operators are all left-associative, but in your own words, can you explain what "input precedence" and "stack precedence" mean exactly?